# Import date from excel in php retuns wrong date

Tags: php, excel, date, phpexcelreader

In my excel sheet the date is "12/15/2014".

After i uploaded it into form the date returns "16/12/2014" in output form.

how can i get actual results that's appear on excel sheet.

Comment: Looks to me like a timezone issue.... how are you getting the date from the Excel sheet, and what's your timezone offset from UST?

Comment: My timezone is asia/calcutta. In excel the date format is "m/d/Y", "12/15/2014". The date increased automatically when i upload the excel. the output returns 12/16/2014.

Comment: The date format and the date are entirely different things..... if you're reading an MS EXcel serialized datetime, then it's a floating point value like 41988.00 with an appropriate number format mask, and you may be getting problems with timezone and the conversion to a PHP datetime. If it's a formatted string, then it's your code that's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

The date function format is `date(Y-m-d);`. So you can upload your date in this format (2015-02-27)

Comment: No kavin. output returns 2015-02-28 but input from excel is 2015-02-27. The date increased automatically.

Comment: try this echo  date('Y-m-d',strtotime(<? php echo "Your date" ?>)).